# How to print Label For Only true boolean values in a class in .Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a class named AccessRole

```
namespace InnovatorYoung.Models
{
    public class AccessRole
    {
        public bool SuperAdmin { get; set; }
        public bool Admin { get; set; }
        public bool Mentors { get; set; }
        public bool Innovators { get; set; }
        public bool AcadPartner { get; set; }
        public bool Guest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I need to print Labels for only the Booleans which are true. Not sure how to do that !

Comment: if ( role.SuperAdmin ) ...

Comment: Yeah, currently I am doing that ! But that doesn't seem efficient adding a if statement for each role. Is there a better way like "where item.value == true" or something else ?

Comment: show different views for different role by using role based authentication..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hardcode, check each properties by name and print out if it's true.
2. Use reflection to get all properties and print out (recommended).

   ```
   AccessRole instance = new AccessRole();
   //...
   Type type = typeof(AccessRole);

   // Loop over properties.
   foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
   {
       string name = propertyInfo.Name;
       object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(instance, null);
       if (value is bool and (bool)value)
       {
           // print...
       }
   }
   ```